# How to read ZeroMQ return values from .recv() and .send() methods in c++?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to write a c++ class for communicating between two computers via ZeroMQ.

To be able to handle errors I am trying to read the return values of the `.recv()-` and `.send()-` methods but I get the following error

> `error: cannot convert 'zmq::send_result_t' {aka 'zmq::detail::trivial_optional<unsigned int>'} to 'int' in assignment
>      ret = msocket.send(reply, zmq::send_flags::none);`

The code looks like this:

```
Publisher::Publisher(dataHandler & mdatahandler) :datahandler(mdatahandler)
{
    // construct a REP (reply) socket and bind to interface

    socketState.bind("tcp://*:5555");
    //socketAngles.bind("tcp://*:5556");
    //socketCurrents.bind("tcp://*:5557");
}

Publisher::~Publisher()
{
    socketState.close();
    //socketAngles.close();
    //socketCurrents.close();
}

std::string Publisher::transfer(zmq::socket_t& msocket, std::string replyString,
    int receiveFlag = 0)
{
    zmq::send_result_t ret = 0;
    if (receiveFlag)
    {
        zmq::message_t receivedData;
        ret = msocket.recv(receivedData, zmq::recv_flags::none);
        if (verbose)
        {
            std::cout << "Received " << receivedData.to_string() << std::endl;
        }
        return receivedData.to_string();
    }
    zmq::message_t reply{ replyString.cbegin(), replyString.cend() };

    // send the reply to the client
    ret = msocket.send(reply, zmq::send_flags::none);

    if (ret == -1)
    {
        std::cout << zmq_strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the socket is defined as

```
zmq::context_t context{ 1 };
zmq::socket_t socketState{ context, ZMQ_REP };
```

How can I reliably catch errors and is there a better way of handling errors if they occur?

*Edit:*
I added the `zmq::send_result_t` but how can I do anything with it? I can't compare it to anything and I can't print it either.

Comment: Use the proper types, and don't reuse variables for multiple purposes.

Comment: I'm relatively new to zeromq. What is the proper type? I tried looking up `zmq::detail::trivial_optional<unsigned int>`but couldn't make any sense of it

Comment: The compiler told you that `send` returns a `zmq::send_result_t`, so use that.

Answer (score 1):

`zmq::recv_result_t` is based on `trivial_optional<unsigned int>`.

`trivial_optional<T>` is a class template that encapsulates that it may or may not contain a value. Instances of type `trivial_optional<unsigned int>` are interrogated with `bool trivial_optional<unsigned int>::has_value()` to see if there is a value.

If there is a value it is extracted using `T trivial_optional<unsigned int>::operator*()` or `T trivial_optional<unsigned int>::value()`.

```
zmq::recv_result_t ret(msocket.recv(receivedData, zmq::recv_flags::none));
if (ret.has_value() && (EAGAIN == ret.value()))
{
    // msocket had nothing to read and recv() timed out
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> **Q** : *"How can I reliably **catch errors** and is there **a better way of handling errors** if they occur?"*

This can be split into two questions:

---

### Part A: "How can I reliably **catch errors**"

First understand the language tools. There are exceptions related tools and best-practices and other Do-s and Don't-s. Obey them.

### Part B: "a **better way of handling errors**"

The best way of handling errors is by **avoiding them** completely - this does not save the Planet ( you can read about Ms. Margaret Hamilton ( she saved lives and national pride on doing this correctly for the Apollo Guidance Computer software ) and her genuine methodology, that saves unavoidable principally colliding cases ).

The next, a lot weaker strategy is to design architectures ( then code ), that thoroughly inspects the state of the system ( return values, RTT-times and other factors ), so as to be continuously ready to handle Exception, as it happens and in full-context with the state of the system ( not to find yourself surprised as standing as uninformed as a blind person in the middle of the crossroads, once the Exception was thrown ... and it will be thrown, at some later time, so be prepared a-priori, not panicking ex-post, resorting to but chaotic ad-hoc options )

### Solution :

**Step 1)**
 Understand and master the language tools.

**Step 2)**
 Understand and master the ZeroMQ tools ( No `REP` can ever start with `.send()` )

**Step 3)**
 Understand and master the published ZeroMQ API, there are all details on details needed for successful Exception handling details ( preventive error-state indications - hidden gems in `{ EINVAL | ETERM | ENOTSOCK | EINTR | ... }` error-states, explained for each and every API call method, in due context for each one such method.

If still not convinced, at least read the fabulous Pieter Hintjens' book ***"Code Connected, Volume 1"***, there one will get the roots of what the Zen-of-Zero is all about.